# "No data available in table" in DataTables

Tags: datatables

I get the message when trying to populate my table. Here's the simplified code.

```js
$("#showUsers").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/showUsers",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,
        complete: function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data.responseText);
            $("#example").dataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [{
                    "sTitle": "Name",
                    "mDataProp": "name",
                    "sDefaultContent": ""
                }, {
                    "sTitle": "Movie",
                    "mDataProp": "movie",
                    "sDefaultContent": ""
                }]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And

```html
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>movie</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The `data` is assigned valid json:

```js
[{
    "name": "Dan",
    "movie": "Amelie"
}, {
    "name": "Rob",
    "movie": "Dungeon"
}]
```

I've read that sometimes it messes with the table itself and the headers and stuff so I tried removing the `<thead>` from my table definition but it results with the same issue.

Funny thing is that, if I replace `"aaData":data` with `"aaData":` plus the json itself, it works. But I can't make `data` fill the requirements needed by DT.

The ajax `data` comes from a `node-mysql` module which is working properly.

If I change `data` to `data.responseText` (this is the json as shown before) I get the warning `requested unknown parameter 'name' from the data source for row 0`.

I know this should be fairly simple for any not-so experienced DataTables user so thanks in advance. Somehow I'm being unable to sort it out.

---

## SOLVED

The MySQL response comes with a `data.responseJSON` which is a working format to give to `aaData`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of flagging the question as awnsered.

**SOLVED.**

The mysql response comes with a data.responseJSON which is a working format to give to aaData. Thanks.

Comment: One would assume that a JSON structure of an Array of Objects would require the `aoData` config property. Turns out the `aaData` config for the provided data works. Weird... This took me forever to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!! But, I have your same problem and I do not understand what I must do exacly. Could you help me?. I answered it too here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211781/datatables-is-not-showing-ajax-results-error-no-data-available-in-table . Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just got wondering why my dataTable was not filling.

In addition to the correct json format needed with `aaData`, `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecord`, `aaData` needs to be an array (`['a', 'b', ...]`) and not an object (`{'a': 'b', ...}`).